# How to represent the following matrix multiplication in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix `A={{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}`, a square 3X3 function which is piecewise constant.. I want to compute `J'AJ`, where `J` is a column vector of all ones and `J'` is the transpose of `J`. I use the following codes:
`PiecewiseExpand[J.A.J]`. However, I fail to obtain the result. How should I amend it?

Comment: What do you mean by "fail to obtain the result", what is the expected result and the actual outcome?

Comment: As A is a piecewise constant function, J'AJ should be a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i, so I try PiecewiseExpand[A.J] first, it works, but when I try PiecewiseExpand[J.A.J], it does not give a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i for piecewise sum. What I can find in my result containing -ve sign and some terms are squared. For simplicity, you may treat a=x, b=x^2, c=x^3, d=x^4, e=x^5, f=x^6, g=x^7, h=x^8, i=x^9 on intervals greater than 1 and 1 less than or equal to 1.

Comment: a=x; b=x^2; c=x^3; d=x^4; e=x^5; f=x^6; g=x^7; h=x^8; i=x^9; {1,1,1}.{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}.{1,1,1} instantly returns x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9 Can you edit your original question to show the actual code which demonstrates the problem you are having?